# Find and Replace all instances of a word with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an article with many instances of the word "color". I set up a button with the class .colour so that if you want you can click it and change the spelling from "color" to "colour" throughout the page. I've written some jQuery to do this but it only changes one instance of the word color but not all. You'd have to keep repeatedly clicking the button to change all of them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".colour").click(function(){
        $("body").children().each(function() {           
            $(this).html($(this).html().replace("color","colour"));
        });
    })
})
```

Is there a way to repeatedly loop the script until it changes all instances? Also is it possible to make it so it is not case-sensitive? I'm new to javascript and jquery so might be a noob question. Thanks

Here's a codepen of it: http://codepen.io/patrickaltair/pen/vcdmy

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have your replace use a regex with a global replace.

Change:

```
$(this).html().replace("color","colour")
```

to:

```
$(this).html().replace(/color/g,"colour");
```

**[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqdaG)**

Comment: Consider using http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1

Comment: @JuanMendes - Yeah I know. Hard habit to break though ;)

Comment: One problem with this is if you have some inline attribute using `color` See [Arun's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25938737/227299)

Comment: @JuanMendes - Then one could use `.text()` instead of `html()`.

Comment: how to include dynamic string there instead of static text color???

Answer (score 11):

I for one am not a big fan of using `.html()` in such cases, so

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".colour").click(function(){
    $("body *").contents().each(function() {
      if(this.nodeType==3){
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/color/g, 'colour')
      }
    });
  })
})
```

```css
h2.colour, h2.color{
  font-size:16px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding:0.4em;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #ccc;
  @include border-top-radius(5px);
  @include border-bottom-radius(5px);
  @include transition (all 0.3s ease-in-out);
}

h2.colour:hover, h2.color:hover{
  color: #000;
  background-color: #aaa;
}



p{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="text">
  Seasonal Colors: Some colors are more appropriate at certain times of year than others. Pastels are usually associated with spring/summer, while autumn colors are rust, <span style="color:brown">brown</span>, <span style="color:green">green</span>, and <span style="color:firebrick">burgundy</span>. Wearing rust in the summer, or light yellow in the fall looks out of place. That color's place in society. Second lower case color.
</p>

<h2 class="colour">Colour</h2>
```

2 problems I see when using .html() are

1. It will replace the dom which means any event handlers/jQuery data attached to those elements will be lost
2. It will replace attributes also which may not be what you want. Notice that I added some color to your text but it's not lost after replacing "color" with "colour"

Comment: What's wrong with `$().html()`? It'd be nice to point out what the advantages of using this are. Not touching existing event handlers is what I can think of. Please help others understand why one should use this

Comment: @JuanMendes it replaces the dom elements... any event handlers used with those elements will be lost... you may not want to replace the attributes, using html will replace that too

Comment: I agree with you in principle on the event handler part, however in this example I don't think it applies.

Comment: I tried this to find a special word and add a tooltip link to it on my site, but it seems it is not possible to use HTML in the replace parameter. Any hints on this?
`$("body *").contents().each(function() {
 if(this.nodeType==3){
  this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/(MyWord(s)?)/g, '<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="Description">$1</a>');
 }
});`

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

Global search in string

```
str = str.replace(/find/g,”replace”);
```

Or global and case-insensitive search in string

```
str = str.replace(/find/gi,”replace”);
```

Answer (score 1):

find all and replace

```
$(this).html().split('color').join("colour");
```

Comment: It's cute, but makes the code hard to read because it's not what you'd usually use split for. It's also slower than the existing answer

Comment: I find no other solution

Comment: It's a bad practice of using split.  Not a good suggestion I would say